# Webpack CSS Chunk Merging

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to generate a single css file with webpack.

I have my app css which is created with `extract-text-webpack-plugin`, that nicely bundles all my css files into one.

The problem starts because we use `google-fonts-webpack-plugin` which downloads the fonts and creates a css chunk that includes the fonts.

My guess is that `extract-text-webpack-plugin` only adds files which were loaded with `ExtractTextPlugin.extract`, and since the fonts chunk is not an actual css file it won't include it.

`CommonsChunkPlugin` also did not help.

I also have tried the using `merge-files-webpack-plugin` which breaks AFAIK because the chunk did not come from a file.

```
const webpackConf = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader']
                })
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'app.css',
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new GoogleFontsPlugin({
            name: 'fonts',
            fonts: [
                { family: 'Titillium Web', variants: ['400', '600', '700'] },
                { family: 'Roboto Condensed', variants: ['400'] }
            ]
        }),
    ]
};
```

How do we create a single css file containing app and fonts?